# How to resume (or launch) my app after a phone call ends in iOS (my app did *not* initiate the phone call)?

Tags: ios, background, launch, phone-call, resume

I have seen several ways to "make sure that my app is shown again after a phone call which my app has initiated has ended" however that isn't what I want -> what I am looking for is a way to, say my app is currently running in the background doing network communications and someone *calls me*, I would like my app to either be able to "detect when the phone call has ended and resume my network communications" and/or "launch/resume my app back into the foreground when the phone call has ended". Is there *any* way to accomplish something like this and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unsupported within iOS.

From the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604

> If your application is active when a call event takes place, the system dispatches the event to your handler immediately. However, call events can also take place while your application is suspended. While it is suspended, your application does not receive call events. When your application resumes the active state, it receives a single call event for each call that changed state—no matter how many state changes the call experienced while your application was suspended. The single call event sent to your handler, upon your application returning to the active state, describes the call’s state at that time.

The best you can do is detect phone calls while your app is open.

Answer (score 1):

`applicationWillResignActive` is called when the app is about move from active to inactive state. So if you get a call, this method is called before your app is backgrounded.

- Use this method to pause any ongoing tasks and save any settings you need.

`applicationDidBecomeActive` is called when you app becomes active again.

- Use this method to resume any tasks that were suspended. Example would be resuming your network communications

Comment: So, if my app is running in the foreground when the call comes in, I agree that this works. However, I am looking for a method to detect a call while backgrounded and, most importantly, when the phone call ends, re-launch my app/resume my suspended (network) operations. According to powerj1984's answer above, it's not possible.. I will wait to see if anyone else give any other answers. But thank you for your response!!

Comment: Yes powerj1984 is correct in that you can't detect phone calls when your app is running in the background, therefore it is impossible have your app re-launch itself when a call ends. Here's a good link on what your app is able to do when backgrounded: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20