# Invoking app in iOS after every phone call ends

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-telephony

I am trying to make an app, which should come into picture (each & every time) as soon as the user is done with his/her phone call.

**Use case**:

"My app" is currently not running.

1. User Makes a phone call from mobile.
2. Once the call is completed, "My app" should start/running.
3. It should gather some information about last call.
4. write it into log & ends..

I have seen tasks running in background foreground but how to invoke App after each phone call.

Thanks..

Comment: impossible. Both scenario 2 and 3 are not possible the 'apple approved' way. Maybe it can be done on a jailbroken iPhone

Comment: @basvk : Thank you for the quick reply. So if I drop the step 2, is it possible to get the list of the recent calls, in "Apple's Approved" way.

Comment: No it's not possible at all without using jailbroken phones icw private api's. And I sincerely hope apple will never enable this either.

Comment: What would you do with this info?

Comment: @nielsbot : I can not disclose the whole idea (Legal Agreements), but to answer, I would say I need it for user's safety & security app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resume (or launch) my app after a phone call ends in iOS (my app did \*not\* initiate the phone call)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492337/how-to-resume-or-launch-my-app-after-a-phone-call-ends-in-ios-my-app-did-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** do this. Quite simply iOS does not (yet) have any such feature where your app would be triggered based on some system event.

But you can explore some alternatives when a call comes when your app is running.

---

**If your app is running when the call comes**

It might be possible to sign up to receive notifications (using `UINotificationCenter` calls) from `UITelephony`.

However, if you're actively using your app when the phone call starts, it will call `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground` when the call is finished. As for differentiating a phone call end versus just a regular return to phone call, I don't know. But it's a start.

If your application is running while a call is in place [CoreTelephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603) provides call states. [`CTCall`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590) class provides information about the call states. I have not used this myself but you may find it useful.

```
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDialing;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateIncoming;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateConnected;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDisconnected;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible to fetch Call/SMS/Email logs in iOS 5 and later.

**You can do this in jailbroke**

any ways if you are trying to achieve this in iOS 4, I have a useful information [HERE](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in iOS till now if the device is not jailbroken.

iOS doesn't allows any app to intercept working of any other application.