# Can you automatically open PWA app after phone call ends

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

One most important feature of my PWA application is to open that app after any call is made.
I don't know how to do that please help me how can I do that

Comment: You would probably need to build a native app to do that. And on iOS it would only work on a phone that is jailbroken. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096950/invoking-app-in-ios-after-every-phone-call-ends